# Data from SQL Server to parameters.in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a quick question for you.

I wrote a program in .NET C#, which loads metadata from my SQL Server. I would like to assign a specific data to the parameter in C#.

For example: I have an `int` number and my query path to this data in SQL Server:

```
SELECT [NumberDB] 
FROM [MY_DATABASE].[MYDB].[MyNumbers]
```

I would like to my int number had value a `[NumberDB]`.

I hope I have easily explained this x)

Comment: do you have any sample code which you have tried, even if we give theoretical answer it might not help you and others who is looking for this question!

Comment: You are confusing SO with Alexa. Did you take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? Use the msdn API on SqlParameter or search SO/google for "C# parameterized query" - read what you find and try it out by coding something. If you then stumble upon a problem, search SO and Google again, and _then_ provide code respecting [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  and your exception / expectation that do not get met by your code and I am sure SO will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

it may be something like this

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    var sql = "SELECT TOP 1 [NumberDB] FROM[MY_DATABASE].[MYDB].[MyNumbers]";

    connection.Open();

    using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        int result = (int) command.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
```